# Discrete Event Simulation Software

Tags: osx, data-visualization, simulation

Does anyone have any good recommendation for Discrete Event Simulation (DES) software for manufacturing, that can run on OSX? I have a few in mind, I have used JaamSim, Delsi 2.0 and Witness (the last on a virtual machine), but none of them satisfied me.

Witness seems to be closer to my needs, which are:

1. It has to have some (at least basic) kind of proper visualisation of manufacturing logistics/shop floor processes integration.
2. It should support extension and new components generation by using a common programming language, such as Java, C++, Python etc. I do not really care about which language, as long as there is this capability.
3. Ideally, it would provide some API to link it to web services, or at least support to write my own.
4. Also, as I mentioned above, it would be good to be manufacturing-oriented and if possible, run on OSX (although that is not a strict requirement).

Answer (score 1):

Paradigm shift.

Try the following:

1. Use JavaScript to encode the simulation logic.
2. Use AcroForm objects for visualization and dynamic visualization. You will need to create the actual visualization of your system components using a vector-based or raster-based software, then export it to PDF and finally import the PDF page(s) into a button. If you have images or shape files available then you can convert them to PDF too.
3. Use AcroForm objects for interaction. Fields such as buttons have a set of decent, basic events for user interaction (e.g. MouseUp, MouseEnter, MouseExit, …). No fancy events like multi-touch, scroll, etc.
4. The Acrobat/JavaScript API (which is supported by software such as Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat) includes basic API for HTTP.
5. I think Adobe Reader and Adobe Acrobat are available for the OSX operating system. They are available for Windows.

If you have a simple example of discrete-event simulation problem at your site then I could try to create a demo simulation of your problem in PDF using AcroForm objects and JavaScript. I will use PowerPoint to create the graphics; but if you have your own graphics then I can use them too.